# Nautilus-Actions 3.1.4 - action ONLY for sftp files

Tags: nautilus-actions

I wrote a script that deletes remote files with root privileges. How to make my menu appears only when I select a file and not a directory? And only for SFTP files and NOT for local files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In action CAPABILITIES add new capability LOCAL and select "Must not match any of" and
in mimetypes tab put in mimetype filter "all/allfiles"